# Conky: a gap between lines: how to remove the space

Tags: ram, conky

I have this in `conky.conf`:

```
${voffset -10}Memory» $hr${color}

${color1}${goto 35}RAM : ${color}${execi 2 free --si -m|awk '/^Mem/{printf "%.2fGiB",$3/1024}'}/$memmax   ${alignr}${execi 2 free --si -m|awk '/^Mem/{printf "%.1f%%", 100*$3/$2}'} \
${execibar 2 free --si -m|awk '/^Mem/{print 100*$3/$2}'}

${color1}${goto 35}SWAP : ${color}$swap/$swapmax $alignr}$swapperc% ${swapbar 4,100}
```

It shows:

[image]

However there is an empty line between `RAM` and `SWAP`. How do I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the blank line in your config file between those two elements.

A blank line is still interpreted. So you need to remove them or start the line with a `#` so it is interpreted as a comment and not a blank line.